# SPNEGO-based Kerberos authentication: Should I create a new security context using `gss_init_sec_context` for every request?

Tags: linux, windows, authentication, security, kerberos

I'm implementing SPNEGO-based Kerberos authentication for a Linux client application for authenticating requests to a Windows IIS server.

I've read RFC4559, which describes how authentication should be performed:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4559

My questions are as follows:

1. Should I create a new security context using `gss_init_sec_context` for every HTTP request, and is it expensive to do so? Curl creates a security context per request, but it only performs a single request: https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/c44671ed431aa3d40819e59f63c471be158480a7/lib/krb5.c#L348
2. How can I use this form of authentication with PUT/POST requests? I don't know in advance from the result of `gss_init_sec_context` whether the server will return HTTP 200 or HTTP 401 Negotiate (continuation). Hence, I don't know when to send the PUT/POST body?

> When using the SPNEGO HTTP authentication facility with client-supplied data such as PUT and POST, the authentication should be complete between the client and server before sending the user data. The return status from the gss_init_security_context will indicate that the security context is complete.  At this point, the data can be sent to the server.

3. It seems ineffective to perform negotiation (authentication) for every request. Why isn't the client authenticated once, with the resulting token being accepted for successive request, like it's the case with OAuth2.0?

**Extra**:

---

**Windows**:

```
securityInterface->InitializeSecurityContext(
    &credentials, hasContext ? &securityContext : NULL, const_cast<TCHAR*>(servicePrincipalName.c_str()),
    ISC_REQ_REPLAY_DETECT | ISC_REQ_SEQUENCE_DETECT | ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY | ISC_REQ_DELEGATE, 0,
    SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP, (inboundData != NULL) ? &inboundBufferDesc : NULL, 0, &securityContext,
    &outboundBufferDesc, &contextAttr, &expiration);
```

**OSX**:

```
OM_uint32 return_flags{0};
OM_uint32 request_flags{GSS_C_MUTUAL_FLAG | GSS_C_REPLAY_FLAG | GSS_C_SEQUENCE_FLAG | GSS_C_CONF_FLAG};
OM_uint32 minor_status{0};
OM_uint32 major_status = gss_init_sec_context(
    &minor_status, GSS_C_NO_CREDENTIAL, (gss_ctx_id_t*)context, (gss_name_t)name, GSS_KRB5_MECHANISM,
    request_flags, 0, GSS_C_NO_CHANNEL_BINDINGS, (gss_buffer_desc*)input_token_x, nullptr,
    (gss_buffer_desc*)output_token, &return_flags, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should I create a new security context using gss_init_sec_context for every HTTP request,

Yes, you should create a new context for each request.

GSSAPI is stateful – each mechanism is done in 'steps' and the API context is what holds this state; it just so happens that the Kerberos mechanism usually finishes in one step. But generally, the first step is what outputs the token you use in the HTTP header, and you cannot repeat it forever; the second step would do something else entirely (for Kerberos it'd take the server's reply and perform mutual authentication), and the 3rd step cannot be performed at all.

If you were using a stateful protocol where the ticket can be sent once and further messages merely MAC'ed, then you would be re-using the same context for the wrap/unwrap or seal/unseal functions; but HTTP does not keep that kind of state.

> and is it expensive to do so?

It should not be. Yes, it's an extra call into the system's GSSAPI or SSPI library, but after you've obtained a ticket once, all further requests for that service principal will be handled entirely offline – you won't be calling into the KDC every time.

In situations where it *is* found to be too expensive, a common pattern would be to protect only a single `/login` endpoint with Kerberos, where your app can trade the Kerberos token for an ordinary HTTP cookie or an OAuth2 token.

> How can I use this form of authentication with PUT/POST requests? I don't know in advance from the result of gss_init_sec_context whether the server will return HTTP 200 or HTTP 401 Negotiate (continuation). Hence, I don't know when to send the PUT/POST body?

If you aren't using the mutual authentication option in GSSAPI, the Kerberos mechanism always completes in one step and there will be no continuations. (The underlying Krb5 call is always single-step, even though GSSAPI wraps it in a stateful framework.) I believe the same goes for SPNEGO when its default mechanisms are used (99% if not 100% of the time), as the initial SPNEGO token will just be a Kerberos token and no negotiation will actually take place.

So if you know authentication will be needed, just proactively get a token and include it in a standard request.

Also, if I remember correctly, you can include an `Expect: 100-continue` in your PUT requests asking the server to return a HTTP 100 Continue after the headers, allowing the body to be delayed.

> It seems ineffective to perform negotiation (authentication) for every request. Why isn't the client authenticated once, with the resulting token being accepted for successive request, like it's the case with OAuth2.0?

No, it's already very much like with OAuth2.0. The client *is* authenticated only once by the identity provider; after you've received a ticket (valid for ~10h), the same ticket gets re-used for every HTTP request you make. The process of creating a GSSAPI context should therefore be very cheap for everything after the 1st request.

Recall that Kerberos was developed almost a decade before SSL/TLS came into existence (and much, much earlier than ubiquitous TLS); its original design was to be used over fully clear-text transports – and indeed even to *provide* the entire secure channel (which you can see being used with NFS or LDAP to this day).

So the biggest difference in design is that Kerberos tokens include a one-time signature to prevent replay attacks. Unlike a bearer token, a Kerberos ticket is not security-sensitive – it comes with a "session key" that provides the security assurance; this key is never sent over the network, but is used to generate one-time tokens that cannot be stolen and replayed like an OAuth2 bearer token could be.

(And this is actually not too different from the fairly recent OAuth1.x, which used per-request signatures; the switch to raw bearer tokens in OAuth2 was a significant departure.)

> You write "Yes, you should create a new context for each request.", how do you see this from the RFC?

Per RFC 1964 section 1.1, the initial output token from client to server contains a Kerberos AP-REQ message (which contains a ticket and an authenticator). Per RFC 1510 section 3.2.2, authenticators cannot be reused; the server will have a "replay cache" to detect authenticator reuse and therefore GSSAPI token reuse.

> When you refer to a Kerberos ticket, you are referring to a Kerberos TGT?

No, I'm referring to the service ticket.

> How does a Kerberos TGS, normally acquired through use of a Kerberos TGT, relate to SPNEGO-based Kerberos authentication?

TGS is not something that is 'acquired'. The TGS (Ticket-Granting Service) is where you acquire tickets **from** – it's one of the two functions performed by a Kerberos KDC.

(You obtain initial TGTs from the AS, then you trade a TGT to obtain service tickets from the TGS – or, optionally, obtain a renewed TGT in the same way.)

> Is the Kerberos token actually a Kerberos TGS?

If by "TGS" you mean "service ticket" – sort of, but not exactly. The GSSAPI SPNEGO token contains a Kerberos AP-REQ message<sup>1</sup>, which contains a Kerberos ticket appropriate for that service **plus** an authenticator (one-time MAC) to prove ownership of the ticket.

<sup>1</sup> (Kerberos very much predates GSSAPI and SPNEGO and had its own authentication token format before the introduction of GSSAPI; this can still be used via direct libkrb5 and found in some older non-GSSAPI software.)

> I will correct you here: "If you aren't using the mutual authentication option in GSSAPI, the Kerberos mechanism always completes in one step and there will be no continuations.". The RFC states that an arbitrary number of steps may take place, and that the client should be able to handle this case

You're confusing Kerberos with GSSAPI. The GSSAPI framework can involve an arbitrary number of steps, but the amount of steps for each specific mechanism is generally fixed. If you're using GSSAPI with Kerberos as the mechanism, RFC 1964 (section 1.1.2, first paragraph) says that exactly one message in one direction is sent when mutual auth is not enabled, and you usually can rely on that behavior.

> "If you were using a stateful protocol where the ticket can be sent once and further messages merely MAC'ed, then you would be re-using the same context for the wrap/unwrap or seal/unseal functions; but HTTP does not keep that kind of state." - will you elaborate here giving an example of a stateful protocol and the names of the wrap/unwrap or seal/unseal functions?

LDAP is one widely used example (and one of the few remaining such examples). It integrates GSSAPI through another framework (SASL) but the two share concepts. Authentication in LDAP is always "persistent" (per-connection, not per-request) – the client and server exchange SASL/GSSAPI messages until auth is done (and both have a "complete" GSSAPI context), then they use the GSS_Wrap() and GSS_Unwrap() functions to encrypt the rest of the connection (or perhaps to provide integrity only, aka 'signing' in Microsoft terminology). These are the messages that actually have the sequence numbers GSS_C_SEQUENCE_FLAG refers to.

See for example the [Cyrus SASL](https://github.com/cyrusimap/cyrus-sasl/blob/master/plugins/gssapi.c#L358-L459) library, which is used by libldap on non-Windows platforms. (Note that 'token' here means a chunk of signed/sealed data, what TLS might call a 'record' – no longer an authentication token.) See also the [SSPI interoperability doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/sspi-kerberos-interoperability-with-gssapi#message-integrity-and-privacy) for a few other functions besides Wrap/Unwrap.

While many protocols use SASL overall (and SASL GSSAPI/GSS-SPNEGO), practically none of them – except for LDAP – use the sign/seal functionality of SASL these days, preferring TLS. But especially in MS Active Directory environments, where TLS needs to be manually set up but Kerberos is guaranteed to always be available, it still finds use daily.

Before GSSAPI, the same features were available in 'raw' Kerberos through krb_mk_priv() and similar functions.

> What's the purpose of Kerberos mutual authentication, when communicating over an encrypted SSL/TLS channel?

> I've added some code to my question for Windows and OSX. In the case of OSX, I can omit the GSS_C_MUTUAL_FLAG flag, and the server won't respond with HTTP 200 and additional continuation data (mutual authentication) to complete the security context. In the case of Windows, I can't disable mutual authentication, as there is no flag for achieving that?

That seems to be ISC_REQ_MUTUAL_AUTH?

> Hence, it always responds with continuation data. In that case, is it safe just to ignore that data and delete the security context?

Yes, you can ignore that data if you're not doing mutual auth; but if I understand the GSSAPI Kerberos mechanism correctly, this is the last step as far as the server cares, so even *with* mutual auth the flow would not change – you can still feed the response into init_context and check the return code locally without having to send anything in return.

> When using Kerberos against Windows IIS, I observe Persistent-Auth: true being returned to the client. This results in all requests being automatically authenticated on Windows, but not on OSX. Do you have any experience with this?

No; at first glance that feels a lot like a leftover from NTLM (which was multi-step and therefore Microsoft decided to make it connection-bound when integrating to HTTP). Though Microsoft's [own docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-n2ht/84d276f8-3632-44e8-a2ff-b169c693049d) regarding this header say it's "part of performance optimization and doesn't guarantee anything".

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge with me! This is more than I hoped for. You write "*Yes, you should create a new context for each request.*", how do you see this from the RFC? I have spend a lot of time looking for an answer to this question (even consulted open-source projects to the best of my abilities)

Comment: When you refer to a Kerberos ticket, you are referring to a Kerberos TGT? How does a Kerberos TGS, normally acquired through use of a Kerberos TGT, relate to SPNEGO-based Kerberos authentication? Is the Kerberos token actually a Kerberos TGS?

Comment: I will correct you here: "*If you aren't using the mutual authentication option in GSSAPI, the Kerberos mechanism always completes in one step and there will be no continuations.*". The RFC states that an arbitrary number of steps may take place, and that the client should be able to handle this case, ending with HTTP 200 and optional (mutual authentication) data

Comment: "*If you were using a stateful protocol where the ticket can be sent once and further messages merely MAC'ed, then you would be re-using the same context for the wrap/unwrap or seal/unseal functions; but HTTP does not keep that kind of state.*" - will you elaborate here giving an example of a stateful protocol and the names of the wrap/unwrap or seal/unseal functions?

Comment: What's the purpose of Kerberos mutual authentication, when communicating over an encrypted SSL/TLS channel? I've added some code to my question for Windows and OSX. In the case of OSX, I can omit the GSS_C_MUTUAL_FLAG flag, and the server won't respond with HTTP 200 and additional continuation data (mutual authentication) to complete the security context. In the case of Windows, I can't disable mutual authentication, as there is no flag for achieving that? Hence, it always responds with continuation data. In that case, is it safe just to ignore that data and delete the security context?

Comment: When using Kerberos against Windows IIS, I observe `Persistent-Auth: true` being returned to the client. This results in all requests being automatically authenticated on Windows, but not on OSX. Do you have any experience with this?